# Combining filters and terms in multiple boolean fields using and

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Suppose we have the following filtering: `field > 0 AND field != value`

I am a bit mixed up on the many ways that elasticsearch has to express that filter using the bool query.Consider the following queries:

Query one

```
"bool":{
    "must_not":{
        "term":{
            "field": value        
        }    
    },
    "must":{
        "range":{
            "field":{
                "gt":0
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Query 2:

```
"bool":{
    "must_not":{
        "term":{
            "field": value        
        }    
    },
    "filter":{
        "range":{
            "field":{
                "gt":0
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Query 3

```
"bool":{
    "must":{
        "bool":{
            "must":{
                "range":{
                    "field":{
                        "gte":value
                    }
                }
            },
            "must_not":{
                "field":value
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Do query 1 and 2 mean the same thing? Also although I have seen many examples in the form of the query 3 (bool query inside a must|should|must_not clause), it produces an error when validating the query:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object'}
```

What does this error mean? How is the correct form? And why so many ways to filter results?

Comment: In query 3 in you  have  "must_not":{                 "field":value             }. Are you missing term query there or what?

Comment: You are right...Didn't see that!!! So it validated true, but what is the difference between those three queries? Is there one? Why so many ways?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Elasticsearch Range Query and Range Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560746/difference-between-elasticsearch-range-query-and-range-filter)